# Facebook SDK logout issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a bit of a problem with the logout process.

A user can go to my app page, click "login with facebook" and then successfully login to the app. They can also click "logout" from my app, which will remove the connection with Facebook and then they will be asked to login again.

The issue I am having is that when a user is already connected with my app and then logs out using the logout feature on www.facebook.com they are still connected with my app. So when they go back to the app page it still thinks they are logged into Facebook.

Has anyone seen this issue before or have any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your really need your user to be logged in with FB, you have to check his login status using FB.getLoginStatus() (that's for the JS SDK)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using JS SDK, however I think this was the only way to solve the issue, by using a combination of PHP SDK and JS SDK.